# How can I use JDT compiler with Gradle 1.0-m9?

Tags: gradle, eclipse-jdt

I prefer Eclipse JDT compiler to javac, and with gradle-1.0-m7 and older, it works this way:

```groovy
compileJava {
    options.compiler = "org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"
    options.encoding = 'utf-8'
    options.define(compilerArgs: ["-warn:+${warnings.join(',')}"])
    doFirst {
        ClassLoader antClassLoader = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader
        configurations.ecj.each { File f ->
            antClassLoader.addURL(f.toURI().toURL())
        }
    }
}
```

But with **gradle-1.0-milestone-9**, I got the following warning (**but still works**):

The `CompileOptions.compiler` property has been **deprecated and will be removed** in the next version of Gradle. To use an alternative compiler, set '`CompileOptions.fork`' to 'true', and '`CompileOptions.forkOptions.executable`' to the path of the compiler executable.

It says `CompileOptions.forkOptions.executable` is the new way to use an alternative compiler. However, JDT compiler doesn't have an executable, and it's designed to be used with ant. (am I right?)

So I'd like to know what's the correct way using JDT compiler with gradle 1.0-m9?

Thanks.

---

Updated Mar 27,

I'v found a way to run JDT compiler 'executable', in fact, by running the java executable

```groovy
compileJava.doFirst {
    def ecjJar = configurations.ecj.singleFile

    options.fork = true
    options.fork executable: 'java', jvmArgs: [ '-cp', ecjJar.path, 'org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main' ]
    options.define compilerArgs: [
        '-encoding', 'utf-8',
        '-source', sourceCompatibility,
        '-target', targetCompatibility,
        "-warn:+${warnings.join(',')}"
    ]
}
```

It works, but looks a little odd:

1. the compiler executable is 'java'
2. I must redirect all compile options to the forked executable, as command line parameters

I'd like to find a more groovy way, at least, ant way to do this.

---

Updated Mar 31,

After digging into the gradle codes, I found the `options.compiler` is the only way to use an alternative compiler with ant (in gradle), for the `AntJavaCompiler` will create a new instance of AntBuilder before compiling, so the ant property `build.compiler` will take no effect here.

So, I will apply the above 'java executable' solution, before a better way be found.

And I've published this solution as a gradle plugin on [GitHub](https://github.com/xinthink/gradle-ecj), hope it helps.

Comment: I would imagine this means that it compiles twice. First with the adt-compiler and then the standard compiler. It should however be nothing left to do. Another problem could any plugins that attach themselves to doFirst on compileJava, but happens after your compilation.

Comment: No, it would not compile twice. There's no compilation during the doFirst phase, options.fork=true tells gradle to use an alternative compiler. I put it in doFirst just because, I cannot get the path of ecj.jar in configuration phase.

Comment: Great plugin, thanks! Finally hot code replace works when using inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it only will be geared against external executable compilers. Maybe you could just override the whole compileJava task?

```
task compileJava(overwrite: true) << {
    ant. ... (run your ant JDT compiler)
}
```

I'm a little uncertain whether there is going to be any side-effects from that though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. The CompileOptions object has a 'useAnt' property, but I don't know how to tell ant to use JDT, without using the 'compiler' property.